# How to build an Android resource bundle

Tags: android

My app is too big. I think I need to break out my resources and have them downloaded separately to external storage. I understand that the way to do this is with a resource bundle. I don't have the foggiest idea how to create such a resource bundle. As a newbie, I need help.

Also, since my app refers to resources, like R.drawable.img01, how do I modify this to access the same resource in the resource bundle?

Thanks,
Clueless

Comment: "I understand that the way to do this is with a resource bundle" -- I am not aware of a "resource bundle" concept in Android.

Comment: Okay, I think I phrased the question incorrectly. I need to break out my resources and put them in external storage. Do I simply create a folder in external storage and download my resource files there? Then how do I reference these resources in my code? (I can no longer use R.drawable.xxx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to break out my resources and put them in external storage.

If you say so.

> Do I simply create a folder in external storage and download my resource files there?

That is certainly one possibility.

> Then how do I reference these resources in my code?

Use standard Java file I/O plus something from Android. For example, for a PNG file, use `BitmapFactory`.